# Write in column X from csv file with BASH

Tags: bash, csv

I need to reformat an csv file. 
From file A i must extract column nr 3 and write it to column 5 in file B

i extract the column with csvtool:

```
csvtool col 3 fileA.csv
```

How to i write the output into the 5th column in file B ?
More to the point, how to i write into a specific column of a csv file using Bash/peral?

I tried the fallowing but with error. Any workaround?

```
csvtool pastecol 5 3 FileB.csv fileA.csv

Fatal error: exception Invalid_argument("List.map2")
```

The desire output will be into the file B

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,  col5,     ,col6,col7,col8
xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx,valuefromfileA,xxx,xxxxx,xxx
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me demonstrate with following test data:

```
fileA
-----
row1
row2

fileB
-----
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6
asdf,qwer,yxcv,tzui,jkl,bnm
```

Now you can simply use `paste` to merge the lines of the files and use `awk` to swap some columns.

```
cat fileA | paste fileB - -d , | awk -v FS=, -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$6}'
```

`cat fileA` represents your `csvtools` of course. The `-` in the `paste` parameters is standard input. `-d ,` sets the delimiter to comma. Same thing with `FS=,` for `awk`. `OFS` is the output field separator to have commas there as well.

Result:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,row1,column6
asdf,qwer,yxcv,tzui,row2,bnm
```